# Dropdown list for boolean attribute does not work properly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, boolean

I have a simple dropdown list for my admin attribute which is a boolean with true/false value:

```
<td><%= f.select :admin, [ ['Yes', true], ['No', false]]%></td>
```

Here is the update method in my controller:

```
def update
 @user = User.find params[:id]
  respond_to do |format|
   if @user.update(user_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User has been updated' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

However, when I update a user to be an admin by selecting "Yes", the user is not updated/saved as an admin... does anyone know what's wrong?? Thanks!!

Comment: can you please post your controller and models codes..

Comment: hey yes i just added it @RajarshiDas

Comment: Please post `user_params` methods as well

Answer (score 7):

You should use `options_for_select` as such:

```
<td><%= f.select :admin, options_for_select([['Yes', true], ['No', false]])%></td>
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease for more info.

Comment: hi - it actually still isn't working... I still can't update admin from true to false.

Comment: Please send us your model too : it may be that your model has no `field :admin, type: Boolean`. It may also be that you did not put `:admin` in your permitted parameters.

Comment: Are you using `form_for :user` at least ?